# Karma test in React app , failing with "TypeError: (0 , _expect2.default)(...).toExist is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, karma-mocha, react-test-renderer

I am new to React, and facing this failing test issue in my app (FilterItems component). Would greatly apprecitate any guidance or help.

Here's my simple FilterItems component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FilterItems extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="filter-items">
        {this.props.data.map(item => (<div className="filter-item">{item.name}</div>))}
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default FilterItems;
```

And here's the test I am running on it, which fails - with the error " **TypeError: (0 , _expect2.default)(...).toExist is not a function
        at Context. (src/tests/FilterItems.test.js:57453:40)"**

My FilterItems.test.js file below

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect';
import FilterItems from '../components/FilterItems';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'; // ES6


describe('FilterItems', () => {
  it('should exist', () => {
    expect(FilterItems).toBeTruthy();
  });
});          


describe('FilterItems', function () {
  it('loads without problems', function () {
    var filterItems = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<FilterItems
      data={ [1, 2, 3] }
      />);

  expect(filterItems).toExist();
  });
});
```

Just in case it helps, below is the karma.conf.js file

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: [
      'src/tests/**/*.test.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/tests/**/*.test.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
  },
  reporters: ['mocha'],
  client: {
    mocha: {
      timeout: '5000'
    }
  },
  webpack: webpackConfig,
  webpackServer: {
    noInfo: true
  }
});
};
```

Comment: I hate to be smarmy, but are you sure `expect(...).toExist` is actually a function? The error seems pretty clear to me

Comment: Am pretty much following this documentation of expect library - https://github.com/mjackson/expect#toexist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this function don't exist in object returned from expect function and documentation is wrong. I'm proposing usage of toBeTruthy alias.